# Flutter filled icons have transparent center symbols, how to give them a color?

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage(photo.path!),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  child: const Icon(
    Icons.warning_rounded,
    color: AppColors.red,
    size: 50,
  ),
)
```

paints this:

[image]

What's the most correct way of making the exclamation mark white?

Comment: Download the [svg](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons+Round:warning:&icon.query=warning&icon.style=Rounded&icon.set=Material+Icons), modify it, use it as SVG asset with [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)